# Google Bigquery API turning dates into Integers

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am running a load job and the dateformat from the pythons DataFrame is turning into an integer. The date format is in UK Time. `01/01/1970 00:00:00`

I have tried to transform it using:

```
pd.to_datetime(appended_data['DateOfBirth'], dayfirst = True, 
               format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors = 'coerce')
```

The format it comes to: `1938-09-01`, however `BigQuery` will then put it in this integer `1012262400000`

Any ideas on the best way to to this. Is it just to put in as a String in `BigQuery` but I have tried to do that with parse and format date, and it's not working?

Comment: What do you mean BQ pust that number? where do you see it? can you edit and post a preview. It will help us to get you an answer

Comment: It sounds like you're working with an integer that is milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Comment: The above example is 01/01/1970 00:00:00 as a string from an API in UK format. There are around 100,000 of these in a column and they all convert into integers.